# How to use mysql command line clients with an alternate port number?

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database was set up to listen on TCP port 3307 instead of 3306. I am trying to use the `mysqldump` command. I wrote the command line like this:

```bash
mysqldump -u root -p database > "path_to_dumpfile\database.sql"
```

Then, I was prompted to enter the password and I get the following error message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (36)

Is there something that I did wrong? or a step that I did not follow?

Comment: `-h localhost --port=3307` instead. the `-p` option forces mysql command line utilities to prompt for a password as well.

Comment: Using `-P` (that's a capital **P**) across all the MySQL command line utilities will specify the port. This is the abbreviation of `--port` that Marc B pointed out.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, also using the --port parameter, and I solved using this suggestion from [a serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/306423/118236):

> When localhost parameter given, MySQL uses sockets. Use 127.0.0.1
>   instead.

Comment: Does not work. 127.0.0.1 still connects to my 3306 mysqld

Comment: yes. Stopping my 3306 instance, I can dump the 3307 instance with the added port parameter. Using localhost or 127.0.0.1 doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: I was trying to dump a database with DBeaver from AWS RDS using port forwarding with Termius. I've changed 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and worked as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Try adding `--port=port_num` or `-P port_num` to your command line like so:

`mysqldump -u root --port=3307 -p database > ..\path_to_dumpfile\database.sql`

I'd recommend you take a look at the MySQL manual to learn of other possible arguments for the `mysqldump` command, link as follows.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 7):

As other suggested, the problem might be the use of wrong protocol when using localhost/127.0.0.1.
So in addition to `--port=3307` also add protocol.

Try:

```
--protocol=TCP --port=3307
```

From `man mysqldump`:

> --protocol={TCP|SOCKET|PIPE|MEMORY}
>
> The connection protocol to use for connecting to the server. It is useful when the other connection parameters normally would cause a protocol to be used other than the one you want. For details on the permissible values, see Section 4.2.2, “Connecting to the MySQL Server”.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem in that I have two instances of mysql running on my server, one on port 3306 and one on 3307.  It appears that mysqldump, even though I specify the port to be 3307, is connecting to the instance at 3306.  My workaround was to shut down the instance running on 3306.  I can only assume that this is a bug with how mysqldump identifies the running instance.

Comment: "My workaround was to shut down the instance running on 3306": this cannot be considered a workaround, as if I need also the 3306 instance, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late for this thread. But It can help someone in the future.

```
echo off 

set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQLWorkbench6.3CE\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost -P3307 ecommerce  > C:\Users\User\Desktop\backmeup\destination_\ecommerce.%TIMESTAMP%.sql
```

As we all know, -p stands for password while -P stands for port.

For some reason, if I use spaces like -u root -p password etc., it will still give an error.

And also, using --databases won't work for me. Instead I added:

```
echo off 

set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%

    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQLWorkbench6.3CE\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost -P3307 ecommerce  > C:\Users\User\Desktop\backmeup\destination_\ecommerce.%TIMESTAMP%.sql 
    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQLWorkbench6.3CE\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost -P3307 equipment_rent  > C:\Users\User\Desktop\backmeup\destination_\equipment_rent.%TIMESTAMP%.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump -u usernameHere -p -h localhost --port=3306  DatabaseNameHere > FileNameHere.sql

Answer (score 0):

for *nix client use `--host=127.0.0.1` and provide `--port=3307` explicitly

`mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 -u root -p database > "path_to_dumpfile\database.sql"`

This is from MySQL docs:

> Only connection options that are relevant to the selected transport protocol are used or checked. Other connection options are ignored. For example, with --host=localhost on Unix, the client attempts to connect to the local server using a Unix socket file, even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a TCP/IP port number.

> To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1 (instead of localhost), or the IP address or name of the local server.

Answer (score -1):

mysqldump --host 192.168.1.1 --port 3307 -u root -pYourrootpassword  --routines --all-databases |gzip > /yourbackuppath/filename_`date +%d`.sql.gz